# Click a hyperlink with onclick event with parameters

Tags: vba, hyperlink

I've done the research part but couldn't get anything which solves my purpose.So i'm posting it

```
<tr>
  <input id="assignmentEnabled" name="assignmentEnabled" type="hidden" value="false"/>
  <td colspan="10"><a href="#" onclick="alterNextEventIdAndSubmitForm('_eventId_changeAssignment')"><img alt="Save" src="/starscontent/images/buttons/change_assignment.jpg" border="0"></img></a></td>
</tr>
```

I need to click the above link. It only has two parameters `href = "#"` and `onclick` which is calling a function. I need to click on **_eventId_changeAssignment** which is inside a function. I tried a lot of codes but none of them worked for me.

```
htmlInput.parentWindow.execScript "alterNextEventIdAndSubmitForm()", "JavaScript"
```

or

```
htmlInput.FireEvent (onclick(alterNextEventIdAndSubmitForm("eventId_changeAssignment")))
```

Comment: Why are you not just clicking the link using something like `htmlInput.click` ?

Comment: @ Tim..I tried that but nothing happened when i click on the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<a href="#" onclick="alterNextEventIdAndSubmitForm();">
```

or

`<a href="#" onclick="Javascript:alterNextEventIdAndSubmitForm();">`

Also inside your javascript function `alterNextEventIdAndSubmitForm` use `document.getElementbyId` to get the required id.

Cheers !!

Comment: @ Sachin...Where should i use the above code. I don't have any Javascript function in my code. I'm using VBA to click on the ablve link.